# Unable to concatenate two lists together

Tags: python-3.x

```
def shift_by_k(numbers, k):
num_to_remove = [numbers[-k:]]
num_to_remove_list = []
for num in range(len(numbers)-1, -1, -1):
    if num >= 4:
        numbers.pop(num)
numbers = num_to_remove + numbers
```

Hi there,

For a practice problem, I need to create a list which takes the last k elements of the list (in this example, the last three elements) and bring them to the front of the list. For example:

numbers = [4, -5, 2, 8, 0, -4, 7] and after doing
print(numbers), you get
[0, -4, 7, 4, -5, 2, 8].

Shown above is the my working to this probem. However, the two lists containing the three numbers which are meant to be put at the front are not adding on to the list; I get [4, -5, 2, 8] only.

I have looked through my code and I just can't figure out what is wrong. What is wrong?

[The full question is here][1]

Edit: With help from @python ged below, these are the outputs I now get:

[0, -4, 7, 4, -5, 2, 8] - when I print, and
[4, -5, 2, 8] - when I return. Why does it not work when I return it? And I'm aware you can do numbers[-k:]+numbers[0:k] but I'm trying to find another solution to the problem

Picture of my output is [here][2]

Still doesn't seem to be working: [enter image description here][3]

*

```
numbers = [4, -5, 2, 8, 0, -4, 7]
shift_by_k(numbers, 3)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the brackets around `[numbers[-k:]]`. I did some adjustements and the below should work for you. But couldn't you also just return `numbers[-k:]+numbers[0:k]`?

```
def shift_by_k(numbers, k):
    num_to_remove = numbers[-k:]
    num_to_remove_list = []
    for num in range(len(numbers)-1, -1, -1):
        if num >= 4:
            numbers.pop(num)
    return num_to_remove + numbers
shift_by_k(numbers,4)
```

**EDIT**:
Now modifies the reference to the list, hence changing the list passed in argument.

```
def shift_by_k(input, k):
    num_to_remove = input[-k:]
    for num in range(len(input)-1, -1, -1):
        if num >= 4:
            input.pop(num)
    for i in range(len(num_to_remove)): input.insert(i,num_to_remove[i])

numbers = [4, -5, 2, 8, 0, -4, 7]
shift_by_k(numbers,3)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but I just tested it and it doesn't work? When I print the list, I get the right answer, but when I return it, I don't

Comment: What do you get when you return?

Comment: I get [4, -5, 2, 8]

Comment: I saw the issue in your printscreen: you are printing `numbers`. However, the function does not modify `numbers`, it returns a modified list, not linked to `numbers`. If you want to print the result you should do `print(shift_by_k(numbers,4))` or `numbers_shifted = shift_by_k(numbers,4)` then `print(numbers_shifted )`.

Comment: still doesn't seem to working, could you check the printscreen for an issue?

Comment: But now you removed the `return` from your function. Keep the return.

Comment: Ah I forgot to return it

Comment: @pythong_ged Really sorry for bothering you further, but actually for the practice test I can't change the bit marked by * above. So how would I go about fixing it if I can't change that part?

Comment: Now the exercise makes more sense, you need to modify the list by using the reference passed to the function. Let me check.

Comment: Updated, have a look.